# How do I change the list item's background after smooth scrolling to it?

Tags: android, android-listview, smooth-scrolling

I'm having an issue fetching the view of the list item when it's off screen.

First I'm smooth scrolling to it

```
//locationsList is a listview
locationsList.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        locationsList.smoothScrollToPosition(k);
    }
});
```

Then I want to do

```
View listItem = locationsList.getChildAt(k);
listItem.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.highlight));
```

How do I call this after it's done scrolling?

Comment: So basically you want to know when the scrolling did complete?

Comment: getview will be called when that position is visible so try to chnage background in getview .

Comment: @Lefteris yea cause getChildAt returns null if the view isnt on the screen

Comment: The getView sounds like a good approach, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Set a unique tag to listitem view. Access this list item with this tag whenever you want to change the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to know is when your scrolling did complete, you need to add an `onScrollListener` to your listview:

```
locationsList.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                if(scrollState==OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
                    View listItem = locationsList.getChildAt(k);
                    listItem.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.highlight));
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            }
        });
```

Of course the above needs a logic to update the background ONLY if scroll has before initiated by you, so you should probably use a boolean flag and set it to true on the `locationsList.smoothScrollToPosition(k);` execution, then if this flag is true, run the code in the scrollListener and set the flag back to false

Comment: not sure why, but it set the scrollState to OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE too fast and the item wasnt on screen yet

Comment: Are you sure it first started to scroll, meaning it passed through your runnable and then called the scrollStateChanged event?

Comment: yea it scrolled for a little bit after my runnable was called.
i put break points to watch the scrollState change and stuff too.

Comment: Weird, this is the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html#SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)

Comment: the getview method works too, but it just seemed gross to me, but it works, so I think i'll go that route since this is being funky. (even though I think this one looks like the correct answer)

Comment: ah, the issue is getChildAt returned null because getChildAt(k) is off screen.  k needs to change because now the item is now in view.